# Type 'AnchoringComponent.Target' has no member 'image'

Tags: swift, realitykit

I created an anchor entity this way and everything worked just fine at first

```
private let imageAnchor = AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR Resources",
                                                  name: "image"))
```

But then I got an error: `Type 'AnchoringComponent.Target' has no member 'image'`

Xcode Version 13.3.1;
MacOS 12.3.1

Can't find any questions related. Any ideas about what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cleaning Derived Data and Build Folder fixed the issue

Comment: It was probably building for the simulator before that - not all ARKit anchors are available via the simulator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).